# Django error. module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'POST'

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am new to Django and I am trying to create a simple web application. I've created a login form and added a hyperlink for signing up for new users. Unfortunately, I got the following error.
module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'POST'

In the bellow you will find view.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, request
from django.db import connection
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import pyodbc

def index(request):
     if 'Login' in request.POST:
          rows = []
          username = request.POST.get('username')
          if username.strip() != '':
               rows = getLogin(username)
               if len(rows) > 0:
                    return render(request, 'login/welcome.html')
               else:
                    return render (request, 'login/index.html')
          else:
              return render (request, 'login/index.html') 
     else:
          return render (request, 'login/index.html')

def newUser(requset):
     if 'NewUser' in request.POST:
          return render(request,'login/newuser.html')

def getLogin(UserName=''):
     command = 'EXEC GetLogin\'' + UserName + '\''
     cursor = connection.cursor()
     cursor.execute(command)

     rows = []
     while True:
          row = cursor.fetchone()
          if not row:
               break
          
          userName = row[0]
          password = row[1]
          name = row[2]
          email = row[3]
                   
          rows.append({'userName': userName, 'password': password, 'name': name, 'email': email})
     
     cursor.close()
     return rows

@login_required(login_url='/')
def readLogin(request):
     if request.user.is_authenticated:
          rows = getLogin()
          return render(request, 'login/loginsdata.html', {'rows': rows})
     else:
          return HttpResponse('You are not authenticated</br>')
```

Here urls.py code of the login app:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('logindata/', views.readLogin, name='logindata'),
    path('newuser/', views.newUser, name='newuser'),

]
```

Here newuser.html code:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lable>Name </lable>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lable>Username </lable>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="username">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lable>Password </lable>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="password">
            </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lable>Confirm password </lable>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" name="confirmPassword">
            </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lable>email </lable>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="email" name="email">
            </td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" colspan=2>
            </td>
        </tr>    
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

And here you will find the index.html page:

```
{% block content %}    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <lable>Username </lable>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <lable>Password </lable>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="Login">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{% url 'newuser' %}" name="NewUser">Sign Up</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="">Forget my password</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
        </tr>    
    </table>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You have a typo in `def newUser(requset):` - 'requset' should be 'request'.

Comment: I corrected it, but I got this error: 
The view login.views.newUser didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After corrected from `requset` to `request` as @gasman pointed. Your `views.py` for `newUser` will be

```
def newUser(request):
    if 'NewUser' in request.POST:
        return render(request,'login/newuser.html')
```

After this you pointed out that you got

`The view login.views.newUser didn't return an HttpResponse object`

It is because there is no `else` part in your `code`. So if your `if` condition fails then your `view` function did not return any response that is why it says `didn't return an HttpResponse object`. So return `HttpResponse` if your `if` condition fails and it will be fine.

```
def newUser(request):
    if 'NewUser' in request.POST:
        return render(request,'login/newuser.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponse() #<-------- if else condition fails.
```

> In your case why it fail's

Because in your `newuser.html` your `submit` button is as follows.

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" colspan=2>
```

And in your views you are comparing the value `NewUser` with `request.POST`. So your `if` condition fails and you are getting this error.

So either change your name as `if 'save' in request.POST` in your `views.py`. Or change `name="save"` with `name="NewUser"` in your `newuser.html` your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the request is a post. So instead of

```
if 'Login' in request.POST:
```

you should check it the following way:

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

Comment: The problem is not in Login, it is in the sign up. The Login is working fine, but the Sing up is not.

Comment: When ypu request `newuser/` via `GET`, there is obviously no POST data.